# Optional foreign key in model related to a model which doesn't exist

Tags: django, model, foreign-key-relationship

I've attempted to add a second ForeignKey relationship to a Django Model which relates to a model which hasn't yet been created.

```
class Forms2012(models.Model):
    """
    Employer forms for the 2012-13 tax year
    """
    employer = models.ForeignKey('Employer', blank=True, null=True)
    # employee model is yet to be implemented
    employee = models.ForeignKey('Employee', blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        choices=constants.FORM_CHOICES)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    datemodified = models.DateTimeField()
```

As you might expect this is giving a `not installed or is abstract` error. However I've been told it should be possible to validate this because that key is optional.

Could someone explain if this is possible, I've added the flags `blank=True, null=True` to the FK but model validation fails so I think I'm fighting a losing battle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you implement a "stub" `Employee` model eg

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    pass
```

If you are using database migrations ( eg South ), which you should, it should be a simple matter to "fill out" the Employee class later on.

However, if you want a fairly involved "solution" to the problem, you can have a look at the accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623854/django-soft-foreignfield-without-database-integrity-checks). The author of the question & answer admits that it is ugly ( even though it works ). The "stub" solution is better.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make (temporary) dummy models?

Comment: Thats what I wanted to do but was advised otherwise. I wasn't sure if there was something I'd missed as I've not been working with Django for very long.

Comment: I wouldn't know why not to do this. Even if you don't use South it is easy enough to drop the dummy table and do a syncdb when you have the actual model done.