# How do i temporarily disable db integrity constraints in django - postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql

I am writing a Django command to seed an existing table,

I need to truncate the table before seeding, but there are foreign key constraints on that table.

because of that, I am getting **django.db.utils.IntegrityError** while truncating the table,

How do I turn the Foreign Key Checks off temporarily in Django?

I saw `SET FOREIGN KEY CHECK = 0` but don't know where to put them :(

**The Django Command class:**

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
help = "Command to seed the aws regions"
regions = [
    {
        'name': 'Us East (N. Virginia)',
        'region': 'us-east-1',
    },
    {
        'name': 'US West (Oregon)',
        'region': 'us-west-2',
    },
    {
        'name': 'EU (Ireland)',
        'region': 'eu-west-1',
    },
]
def handle(self, *args, **options):
    self.stdout.write('seeding regions...')

    AwsRegions.objects.all().delete() # this is where i get errors

    for name, region in self.regions:
        self.stdout.write(region)
        AwsRegions.objects.create(name, region)


    self.stdout.write('done seeding regions')
```

Comment: `SET FOREIGN KEY CHECK = 0` seams like a MySQL query to me..

Comment: Well the PostgreSQL docs give a hint "The firing of **triggers** that are declared as **"constraint triggers"** is also controlled by this setting " https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-set-constraints.html  so i assume you can disable that "constraint" trigger with `ALTER TABLE table DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;`  and to actived it again `ALTER TABLE table ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Got the solution.

I had to disable the Triggers on the table to stop the foreign key constraint check.

**Disable Triggers**

```py
def disable_triggers(self):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('ALTER TABLE "Table Name" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;')
```

**Enable Triggers**

```py
def enable_triggers(self):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('ALTER TABLE "Table Name" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;')
```

**Important Notes**:

- According to [this doc link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/sql/#connections-and-cursors), you can pass a list as the second argument to the `execute()` method (eg: you might want to pass the table name dynamically), but this will automatically escape the variables and you might end up forming a syntactically wrong PostgreSQL query (which took a lot of my time to fix it)
- Make sure you turn the triggers back on properly
- If you are getting a ***Permission denied error***  Then you might want to check the DB user permissions, I just turned on superuser permissions from PgAdmin, which was ok for me. and everything back to work. [How to do it ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52768479/2693543)

Comment: Nice solution, however it appears to be using raw SQL. Do you by any change know a solution that uses the Django ORM so it would be DBMS agnostic?

Comment: Well. I wasn't able to find an ORM solution, But what I did was to include this in the script.

Answer (score 2):

To disable triggers for all tables (useful when you need to stop it for multiple tables):

```
SET session_replication_role TO 'replica'
```

And to restore:

```
SET session_replication_role TO 'origin'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.db import connection
with connection.constraint_checks_disabled():
    do_stuff()
```

Credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/11926432/2558400