# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: permission denied: "RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_25437" is a system trigger

Tags: django, postgresql, triggers

I am trying to disable the triggers for one of my PostgreSQL table using the following code

```
def disable_triggers(self):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('ALTER TABLE "frontend_awsregions" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;')
```

But this is giving me following error

> ... 
>   ...
>   return self.cursor.execute(sql)
>   django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: permission denied:
>   "RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_25437" is a system trigger

when I execute the same query in PGAdmin, its working properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went and turned on the superuser permission from PgAdmin for the current DB user. and it fixed it for me.

[image: Enable superuser permissions from PgAdmin]